# I get intent error for create alarm clock

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I would create an  alarm clock, i wrote this code but return this error:

> 2019-02-05 10:58:13.902 2663-10077/com.google.android.gms
>   E/ChromeSync: [Sync,SyncIntentOperation] Error handling the intent:
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
>   dat=package:com.example.iacopo.alarmgroup flg=0x4000010
>   cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService (has
>   extras) }.

How can i fix it? thanks
And this code doesn't create a icon af alarm in the notification panel, near the clock

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.clear();
        cal.set(2018,1,5,10,0);

        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        this.startService(intent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

and the receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("test","ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jTx35VL7fT0TCozfdAAWgdA6y89AOanlvOm9qa_DEIs/edit?usp=sharing